# Seeking clarification on unarmed attacks and brawling weapons

Tags: unarmed-combat, natural-weapon, dungeons-the-dragoning

For Dungeons the Dragoning, I have some confusion about unarmed attacks versus brawling weapons.  The description of the "Brawling" tag for weapons (203 of the core book) is as follows:

> The damage from a Brawling weapon is added to the user's unarmed
>   attacks. Brawling weapons use the Brawl skill rather than the Weaponry
>   skill.

Now, it is possible (via the weapon customization rules in For a Few Subtitles More) to generate a brawling weapon that counts as Razor Sharp, and the original book has Power Fist, which has a Power Field.  Thri-kreen can get built-in toxic mandibles.  These are things that include effects beyond the pure damage roll.  We also have the monk track (in FaFSM), which gives bonuses specifically to unarmed attack, and the Setting Sun sword school (in the base book) which allows use of unarmed attack.

So... I'm trying to figure out how this fits together.  I sort-of see two possibilities:

- If I attack with a brawling weapon, I automatically get to just add whatever unarmed benefits I might have on to it (including the base 0k1 damage)
- I need to choose between attacking unarmed (in which case I get all of the unarmed stuff, plus the damage from my brawling weapon, but nothing else) or attacking with the brawling weapon (in which case I get whatever special effects my brawling weapon might have, but lose out on the unarmed attack stuff)

...and if it's the second, is there anything in the rules that would prevent me from strapping a Power Fist on each hand and claiming damage bonuses from both of them?  I mean, I'd never expect a GM to go for it, but is there anything in the rules actually preventing it?